# Compile Erlang in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, erl, beam

I try compile erl files in Intellij with Erlang plugin. Everything is good with compilation but in out/production the folder does not create any files `.beam` and when I run console I get message:

```
exception error: undefined function.
```

When I use `c("file").` everything is all right. Why does Intellij not create `.beam` files?

Comment: Do you compile with rebar? What is your project layout?

Comment: No, without rebar but my function are very simple like factorial. My friend use Intellij with Erlang plugin without any problems but I have.. I install Intellij and Erlang plugin, then I create new project with Erlang 18 SDK. I create new Erlang file in src folder. I should get beam file in production folder but I have nothing omitting "Compilation completed successfully" in log. When I write in Erlang console in Intellij cd(src). and c("file")., I create file beam and everything work..

Comment: What do you mean `production` folder? Is it `production` or `ebin`?

Comment: When I clicked compile in my project's folder was created out/production and I think in this folder should was created beam file.

Comment: It depends on 'Project structure' paths actually. Check them. Also check if you setup sdk path correcly

Comment: Structure and sdk path is correctly.. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try to fix it by going to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Erlang Compiler and check "Compile project with rebar".
Also, verify that rebar is installed and configured in IntelliJ by going to Preferences -> Other Settings -> Erlang External Tools and specifying the path to the rebar installation.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue ..

The problem is very strange erlang plugin doesn't compile and copy the files to `out` directories meanwhile if you compiled from terminal or command prompt (windows) it is working fine. this issue arose after installing IntelliJ Idea v 15.

What I have done here to fix the issue:

> - Uninstall Intellij Idea v 15
> - Downgrade IntelliJ Idead to [version 14.1.4](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Previous+IntelliJ+IDEA+Releases)
> - Install Intellij Idea again (v. 0.5.11)
> - Configure SDK to reference src of erlang language.
> - Create a new test project and start making the project again .. it should work fine...

Hope this helps you